# How do I use a bash file without '.'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I want to use bash files, I have to write this.

. name.bash

[image]

---

However, the bash file below does not work when run with '.' attached.
If I use this command, the file is deleted immediately. (not move trash)
ex) . trash.bash  del.txt

When I ask, they say "." should be removed.
However, if I remove '.', I will see "Command not found".

I have only recently learned Linux.
So, I do not know if the bash code below is wrong, or it does not work with '.'.

```
#! /bin/bash

FCnt=0
LFlag=0
PFlag=0
IFlag=0
FFlag=0
trash=~/.trash

error ()
{
cat << END
echo How to use the Recycle Bin management program :
echo   trash -p : "Empty the trash"
echo   trash -i : "Empty Trash (OK or No)"
echo   trash -l : "Recycle bin check"
echo   trash file* : "Throw in trash"
END
exit 1
}

for list in $*
do
  case $list in
    "-p")
        PFlag=1
        ;;
    "-i")
    IFlag=1
    ;;
    "-l")
        LFlag=1
        ;;
    "-*")
        echo $list : wrong
    error
        ;;
    *)
        FFlag=1
        fileList[$FCnt]=$list
        let FCnt=FCnt+1
        ;;
    esac
done

let total=$LFlag+$PFlag+$FFlag+$IFlag
if (( total != 1 ))
then
   error
fi

if [ ! -d $trash ]
then
    'mkdir' $trash
fi

if (( LFlag == 1 ))
then
   'ls' -lgF $trash
   exit 0
fi

if (( PFlag == 1 ))
then
   'rm' $trash/*
   exit 0
fi

if (( IFlag == 1 ))
then
   'rm' -i $trash/*
   exit 0
fi


if ((FFlag == 1 ))
then
   'mv' ${fileList[*]} $trash
   exit 0
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: `chmod u+x 10.3.bash` and then `./10.3.bash` or only `bash 10.3.bash`.

Comment: I always run chmod +x and then run the bash file. Should I do 'chmod u+x'?

Comment: It makes no difference in the context of your question. `chmod +x` grants more rights than may be intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

First notice there is **no space** between `#` and `!`.

And if you want to execute the shell script without `.`, you need to add the directory where the script is to `PATH`.

- `sudo vim /etc/profile`
- add `export PATH="/home/xxxx/bin:$PATH"` at the end of document, replace `/home/xxxx/bin` with your directory you want.
- save and exit
- `source /etc/profile`

And then you can execute it in every directory if without mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Executing the file as `. name` `source`s the script, which runs it in your shell's context, not as its own process.  That means it can modify your environment.  Sometimes that's what you want, sometimes it isn't.

If you don't want it, you can make the script executable with `chmod +x name` or similar.  Then you can execute the script by specifying the path to it.  You can always provide the full absolute path or you can use a relative path, with `.` being the current directory so `./name` will look in the current directory for it and run it.  Alternately, if you put it in one of the directories in the `PATH` variable the shell will find it just by name, without the path being required.

If you don't want to make the script executable you can always run the shell explicitly and tell it to process the file like `bash name` where `name` can be in the current directory or any path to the file you want to run.

Comment: Note that `.` is short for `source`.